# Refactoring Many Methods into One

Tags: c#, jquery

I dont know how to name the question properly, so fell free to change it. My question is, I have around 10 methods that look like:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string ReadUserAdditional()
{
    EUser user = (EUser)Session["user"];

    var json = new { result = true, user.Image, user.Biography };

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(json);
}


[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string ReadUserBasicInformation()
{
    EUser user = (EUser)Session["user"];

    var json = new { result = true, user.Name, user.Username};

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(json);
}
```

The methods are very similar, but they return different fields. Im thinking about refactoring all methods into one, receveing the fields to return as parameters. Is it a good idea? How can I do that? Reflection?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a 2nd similar method so we can see what is the same/different between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to know that object and dictionary are presented in json simmilar.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string ReadUserAdditional()
{
    return GetUserInfo(new [] 
    {
        new FieldInfo {Name = "Image", u => u.Image},
        new FieldInfo {Name = "Biography", u => u.Biography} 
    });
}

private string GetUserInfo(FieldInfo[] infos) 
{
    EUser user = (EUser)Session["user"];

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "result", true } };
    foreach(var info in infos) 
    {
        dictionary.Add(info.Name, info.Accessor(user));
    }

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict );
}

public class FieldInfo 
{
    public Func<EUser, object> Accessor { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: @myself, it is cheapest solution, because there is no reflection.

Comment: Also serializing of Dictionary should be cheap then serializing of anonymous object, becouse when serializer do serialization of object it uses reflection.

Comment: hazzik, what about the security issue pointed by Mike? (if its not ask too much rs)

Comment: @myself in my sample your control which data should be sent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a terrible idea, especially if you have tons of these methods and want to simplify your API.

A few downsides:

1) Reflection comes at a perf cost.  This probably doesn't matter a whole lot unless you're the size of Twitter.

2) There would potentially be security concerns if the data had any properties you do NOT wanting users getting access to, such as some sort of internal database keys or what not.  Make sure every property on your class is one you're totally okay becoming public information.

Comment: Yeh, I think you are right, the performance cost and the security of each property (the second one I can work around by creating a custom attribute and adding it to specific fields, if theres not one already to prevent properties to be read by reflection).

Comment: Would caching the `PropertyInfo` objects help performance in .NET? Instead of using any string as a field key, you could make the string an index into a dictionary of "allowed" `PropertyInfo` descriptors, which would help both with performance and security.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda to refactor away the duplication:.  This would reduce all your methods to a single line of code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string ReadUserAdditional()
{
    return GetUserJSON(x => new { result = true, x.Image, x.Biography });
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true]
public string ReadUserBasicInformation()
{
    return GetUserJSON(x => new { result = true, x.Name, x.UserName });
}

private string GetUserJSON(Func<EUser, string> jsonFields)
{
    EUser user = (EUser)Session["user"];
    var json = jsonFields(user);
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) or similar library to project your data.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string ReadUserAdditional()
{
    return GetUserInfo<UserAdditionalDto>();
}

private string GetUserInfo<TDto>(FieldInfo[] infos) 
{
    EUser user = (EUser)Session["user"];

    var dto = Mapper.Map<TDto>(user); // Mapper is Automapper entry class.

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dto );
}

public class UserAdditionalDto
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set;}
}
```